# Editing Radar Charts for Labeling and Axis Limits

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib, radar-chart

I have been playing with the `radar chart` concept for visualizing percentage-based metrics.  I have followed sample code but am having trouble with a few items.  Can anyone help me with changing the labels from the default degree values to something else?  I also want to set the x-axis minimum to 0.9, but struggled a bit.

Any help or resources are helpful.  If there is a more efficient way to solve them, I am open to starting over again.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

availability_array = np.array([.95, .9, .99, .97, 1]) #sample inverter uptime availability numbers using site with 5 inverters

# Compute pie slices
theta = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, len(availability_array), endpoint=False)
values = availability_array #values that are graphed
width = 1 #increase/decrease width of each bar

ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar') #.set_xticklabels(['N', '', 'W', '', 'S', '', 'E', '']) #111 means 1x1 grid subplot starting in cell 1

bars = ax.bar(theta, values, width=width, bottom=0.0)

# Coloring
for r, bar in zip(values, bars):
    bar.set_facecolor(plt.cm.viridis(r / 1))
    bar.set_alpha(0.4) #transparency of the bars

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've already shown in your comments, labels around the circle are `xticklabels` and labels along the radius are `yticklabels`, i.e. y-axis is along the radius. Therefore, I think you meant to "set the ***y-axis*** minimum to 0.9".

As you would do with regular plot, you can use `set_xticks` in combine with `set_xticklabels` to change "the labels from the default degree values to something else". For example:

```
ax.set_xticks([np.pi/4, np.pi*3/4])
ax.set_xticklabels(['NE', 'NW'])
```

To "set the ***y-axis*** minimum to 0.9", you can use `set_ylim` like this:

```
ax.set_ylim(0.9, 1)
```